# Woocommerce product not responsive

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, responsive

I am trying to improve the rersponsiveness of my woocommerce product pages for mobile devices, e.g. here:
https://pvcarport24.de/pv-loesungen/solar-carport-stahl/

It seems like the class wp-embed causes the page width to be larger than the mobile device screen (not 100% sure). I have used firefox developer options to determine that.

Afterwards, I tried adding additional CSS using the Wordpress Design Tab (Theme: Hello Elementor)

and added following Code, which had no effect at all.

```
.copyfooter {
    text-align: center;
}

.wp-embed {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .wp-embed {
        width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .wp-embed {
    width: 450px;
    height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try also setting `max-width: 100%`